# Mysql count per distinct user with a join

Tags: mysql

currently i have two tables with some data. the first table has the following:

```
+----------------+-----------+
| name           | member_id |
+----------------+-----------+
| Juice Box      |     49432 |
| Rainsurge      |     49631 |
| spiderpigrider |     50482 |
+----------------+-----------+
```

The second table has the following:

```
+------------+-----------+
| recruit_id | bin(refs) |
+------------+-----------+
|      49432 | 1         |
|      49631 | 1         |
|      49432 | 1         |
|      49631 | 1         |
|      49432 | 1         |
|      49631 | 1         |
|      49432 | 1         |
|      49631 | 1         |
|      49432 | 1         |
|      49631 | 1         |
+------------+-----------+
```

I would like to return the name, total refs and member_id/recruit_id like so (listing only users with at least 1 ref)

```
+------------+-----------+------------+
| recruit_id | name      | total_refs |
+------------+-----------+------------+
|      49631 | Rainsurge |          5 |
|      49432 | Juice Box |          5 |
+------------+-----------+------------+

select r.recruit_id,bin(r.refs),ipb.name from refs as r 
inner join syndicate_ipb.core_members as ipb on ipb.member_id=r.recruit_id;
```

this returned my data but obviously without a total count and repeated names/ids

```
select r.recruit_id,count(bin(r.refs)),ipb.name from refs as r 
inner join syndicate_ipb.core_members as ipb on ipb.member_id=r.recruit_id;
```

this returned data with the total count of everyone but only one id/name

```
+------------+--------------------+-----------+
| recruit_id | count(bin(r.refs)) | name      |
+------------+--------------------+-----------+
|      49432 |                 10 | Juice Box |
+------------+--------------------+-----------+
```

this returns the data but again without a count

```
select distinct r.recruit_id,bin(r.refs),ipb.name from refs as r 
inner join syndicate_ipb.core_members as ipb on ipb.member_id=r.recruit_id;

+------------+-------------+-----------+
| recruit_id | bin(r.refs) | name      |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
|      49432 | 1           | Juice Box |
|      49631 | 1           | Rainsurge |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated. I feel like i'm close here but just not competent enough with SQL to get it. thanks!

Comment: You are almost there! You need to group by `r.recruit_id`. **Here it is:** `select r.recruit_id,count(bin(r.refs)),ipb.name from refs as r 
inner join syndicate_ipb.core_members as ipb on ipb.member_id=r.recruit_id
GROUP BY r.recruit_id;`

Comment: OMG that was it!! lol can you post this as the answer so i can accept! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. You just missed the `GROUP BY` clause at the end.

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    r.recruit_id,
    count(bin(r.refs)),
    ipb.name
FROM refs AS r
INNER JOIN syndicate_ipb.core_members AS ipb 
ON ipb.member_id = r.recruit_id
GROUP BY r.recruit_id;
```

**Note:**

If `bin(refs)` column always contains value 1 then actually you don't need to keep that column. In that case you can use `count(*)` or `count(r.recruit_id)` to get the count.

And if `bin(refs)` column contains any value then `count` will not give you the right answer. In that case you need to use `sum` like `Sum( bin(refs))`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `group by` clause:

```
select r.recruit_id, ipb.name, count(bin(refs)) as total_refs
  from refs as r 
         inner join syndicate_ipb.core_members as ipb 
                 on ipb.member_id=r.recruit_id
 group by r.recruit_id, ipb.name
 having count(bin(refs)) >= 1
```

This `group by r.recruit_id, ipb.name` will group the results and this `having count(bin(refs)) >= 1` will garante that it only returns members with at least one ref

Do not only group your columns just by the ones you want. Even though MySql allows it, it is not SQL Ansi pattern and even MySql now is complying with it. Use an aggregation function grouping with your entire columns on the select statement.

Comment: perfect, i was actually going to work on adding a where clause and you anticipated me :D

Comment: Glad that I could help.

Comment: you were a great help, but i have to accept 1000111's as they provided the correct answer in a comment about 6 minutes ahead of you. Just waiting for them to add it as an answer! thanks again!

Comment: That's no problem. When I started to answer there was no comment yet, but he must have sent the comment before I finish to write it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ipb.*, COUNT(`r`.`recruit_id`) AS cid FROM `ipb` 
INNER JOIN `r` ON `r`.`join_id` = ipb.`member_id`
GROUP BY ipb.`member_id`
```